# SQLite full-text search with multiple tokens using a prepared statement

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, prepared-statement

Given the following tables:

```
create table index(name text, docid int);
create virtual table docs using fts4();
```

The following query works as intended when querying for a single token (for example: `march`, or `bad`):

```
select name from index where docid in (select docid from docs where docs match ?)
```

But how can I query for more than one token (say, `bad bed`)? Binding the string `bad bed` directly does not work (always selects nothing), neither surrounding the placeholder or the string with double quotes, nor using `AND` to `MATCH` each token separetly (this last one throws an error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `intersect` does work, but it's clunky and innefficient when searching for many tokens:

```
select name from index where docid in (
    select docid from docs where docs match ?
    intersect
    select docid from docs where docs match ?
    intersect
    ...
)
```

Each `?` is paired with a single token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concatenation operator `||` in sqlite. `''` would be the empty string

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE docs MATCH '' || ? || ' ' || ? || ' ' || ? || ''
```

Make sure there is a space between every token or an `' AND '`.

**Update**

Actually it doesn't work. It seems there are tokenator issues with this approach. Its better to concatenate all the tokens with the space and bind the resulting string with a single '?'

Answer (score 0):

There are operators within the match syntax in FTS so you can use `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`.

[See here for documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_1)

e.g.

```
-- Return the docid values associated with all documents that contain the
-- two terms "sqlite" and "database", and/or contain the term "library".
SELECT docid FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'sqlite AND database OR library';
```